# How do I edit MySQL table column properties with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I need to edit a field type in a MySQL table.  Currently I have this one column set as VARCHAR that I need to change to an INT.  The catch is that I do not have access to the control panel so I cannot simply flip the switch.  How do I go about making this edit with PHP?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just execute an [`ALTER TABLE` statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html)

```
ALTER TABLE tablename MODIFY columnname INT;
```

In PHP:

```
$result = mysql_query("ALTER TABLE tablename MODIFY columnname INT;");
```

If you require extra attributes on that column, such as `NOT NULL`, `PRIMARY KEY`, or others, be sure to include them in the `ALTER` statement, just after the data type `INT`.